# To which internal temperature should I cook beef for rare/medium/well done?

Tags: beef, temperature

I am going to cook a beef roast: To which internal temperature should I cook it for rare/medium/well done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
|  Rare         |  120 °F to 125 °F  |  49 °C to 52 °C   |  center is bright red  |
|  Medium Rare  |  130 °F to 135 °F  |  54 °C to 57 °C   |  center is very pink   |
|  Medium       |  140 °F to 145 °F  |  60 °C to 63 °C   |  center is light pink  |
|  Medium Well  |  150 °F to 155 °F  |  66 °C to 68 °C   |  not pink              |
|  Well Done    |  160 °F and above  |  71 °C and above  |  brown throughout      |
```

Comment: grrrrr, I'm having trouble finding the source, but I'd like to point out that the US gov doesn't agree with these numbers at all. Their numbers are much higher. However, I agree with hobodave. The gov is much closer to the numbers on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beef#Internal_temperature

Comment: @yoss: yea, the chart tends to differ by about 5 degrees depending on where you read it

Comment: @yossarian - every cookbook I've ever read says that the USG is quite overcautious with their measurements.

Comment: @justkt, Yes. I agree whole heartedly and use the same temp guidelines as hobodave (well, actually I don't have any use for them past 135F). I was just pointing out that the USG didn't agree.

Comment: You forgot 'blue'

Comment: Officially I think the government says 140 for rare.  However, I agree with the table above if you are planning to "rest" the meat ... meaning, I would pull it out of/off the heat and tent it with tinfoil for 15 minutes to let the juices settle and also let the internal temperature come up a bit more.  I find this makes for a HUGE success.

Comment: I'm curious why there are 5°F gaps between these ranges?

Answer (score -2):

For some different values see http://healthycanadians.gc.ca/eating-nutrition/safety-salubrite/cook-temperatures-cuisson-eng.php

/
.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.